# Where to properly deallocate bitmap on Android View?

Tags: android, view, bitmap, android-custom-view

I have a custom View, that draws a bunch of stuff including bitmaps.  I want to cache this drawing onto a bitmap, so that I just need to draw one single bitmap inside onDraw, rather than repeating these drawing tasks and calculation.

Bitmaps need to be recycled after we are no longer using it. I don't see onDestroy() or anything remotely similar in the View class. Is there a callback method I can override to achieve this?

```
public void <insert_callback_here>() {
    cachedBitmap.recycle();
}
```

There is no animation.  This is a static image.  There are plenty of calculations done to draw the image, so I'd rather do it once on onMeasure().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own here.  The proper methods to override is `onDetachedFromWindow`.  I deallocate my bitmap inside `onDetachedFromWindow`, and reallocate them inside `onMeasure` if the width or height have changed.

```
@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    if (cachedBitmap != null && !cachedBitmap.isRecycled()) {
        cachedBitmap.recycle();
        cachedBitmap = null;
        cachedBitmapWidth = -1;
        cachedBitmapHeight = -1;
    }
}

protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);;
    int viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);;

    if (cachedBitmapWidth != viewWidth || cachedBitmapHeight != viewHeight) {
        if (cachedBitmap != null) {
            cachedBitmap.recycle();
        }
        cachedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        cachedBitmapWidth = viewWidth;
        cachedBitmapHeight = viewHeight;
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cachedBitmap);
        // do drawings here..
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(viewWidth, viewHeight);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Just to add, I also ran a System.gc() after recycling the bitmaps, as I was having problems with having enough memory.

Comment: Nice, but be careful about apps where you call finish () from onCreate (): it can make a memory leak that way (see https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/android-leak-pattern-subscriptions-in-views-18f0860aa74c).

Comment: Also important: it's bad practice to allocate anything inside onMeasure () and onDraw (). For example, depending on your layout hierarchy, onMeasure () is called like 2 or 3 times before the final size of the view is determined. Reallocating inside onSizeChanged () would be better.